# Create single pandas dataframe from a list of dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a list of about 25 dfs and all of the columns are the same. Although the row count is different, I am only interested in the first row of each df. 
How can I iterate through the list of dfs, copy the first row from each and concatenate them all into a single df?

Comment: @DYZ - OP need something else, because partly dupe reopened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select first row by position with [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and `[[0]]` for one row DataFrames and join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat([x.iloc[[0]] for x in dfs], ignore_index=True)
```

Or use [`DataFrame.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html) for one row `DataFrame`s:

```
df = pd.concat([x.head(1) for x in dfs], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: can you use .iloc if the row indices are unnamed?

Comment: @NayyNeww - yes, it select first row, not important what is index values.